# Coldfusion to PayPal Express REST API Error: No Value Passed to Payment

Tags: javascript, php, json, paypal, coldfusion

Setting up connection to PayPal Express checkout with ColdFusion, I'm getting this error - `"Uncaught Error: No value passed to payment"` while  using PayPal Express Checkout and checkout.js from PayPal.
Here is my code where I create PayPal payment and return paymentID in  JSON stored in `paypal.cfm` file on my site:

```
 <cfset aresponse = deserializeJSON(cfhttp.FileContent)>

 <cfheader statusCode = "200"  statusText = "OK">
 <cfheader  name="Content-Type"  value="application/json">
 <cfheader name="Accept-Language" value="en_US">

  <cfset res = StructNew()>
  <cfset res = {"paymentID" = aresponse.id}>
  <cfset res = serializeJSON(res)>
  <cfoutput>#serializeJSON(res)#</cfoutput>
```

And here is the js code with PayPal button where my `paypal.cfm` file is called to create payment and get paymentID from it to pass to PayPal:

```
<script>
    paypal.Button.render({

        env: 'sandbox', // sandbox | production

        commit: true,

        payment: function() {


            var CREATE_URL = 'https://example.com/paypal.cfm';

            // Make a call to your server to set up the payment
            return paypal.request.post(CREATE_URL)
                .then(function(res) {
                      return res.paymentID;
                });
        },

        // onAuthorize() is called when the buyer approves the payment
        onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {

            var EXECUTE_URL = 'https://example.com/paypalex.cfm';

            var data = {
                paymentID: data.paymentID,
                payerID: data.payerID
            };

            return paypal.request.post(EXECUTE_URL, data)
                .then(function (res) {
                    window.alert('Payment Complete!');
                });
        }

    }, '#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

So, I successfully create payment and when I call pp-json.cfm directly I create JSON response that contains paymentID in the following format: `{"paymentID":"PAY-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"}` But when I try to use it with the PayPal button, I get the error saying `Error: No value passed to payment (checkout.js line 2857)`
Anyone knows what it could be?? Is any JSON response incorrect? If so, what should it be? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you `console.log('Payment ID:', res.paymentID)` what do you see?

Comment: Thank you bluepnume, you sent me in the right direction! Got it now!